# Does these HDD free space values look normal? Is there something wrong with my system?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, 15.10

I have been using Windows 8.1 and changed to Ubuntu 15.10 today. I erased Win 8.1 and installed Ubuntu. I have a 500GB HDD with 4GB ram. But when i checked the Computer properties i found this:

```
     Free Memory : 456.6 GB
     Used Memory: 6.8GB
     Total Capacity:488GB
```

But i have a 500GB HDD, What happend to the missing (approx) 40Gbs? Then why does it show Total Capacity as just 488GBs? Then i checked the partitions using lsblk command.

```
         NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 461.9G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr1     11:1    1   128M  0 rom
```

This was the result. Is there anything wrong with my system or the installation? Or are these normal values?

Answer (score 1):

It shows as less because hard drive *manufacturers usually measure size in steps of 1,000. (1 kilobyte = 1,000 bytes, 1 megabyte = 1,000 kilobytes. 1 gigabyte = 1,000 megabytes.) So, according to these manufacturers, a 500GB drive would be 500,000,000 bytes.

However, operating systems (with the exception of Mac OS) measure storage in steps of 2¹⁰ (1024), so 1 kilobyte would be 1,024 bytes instead.

This means that the hard drive will actually have less capacity *according to the OS* than what is advertised *by the manufacturers*. Manufacturers have done this since very early in the IT industry's history, to save money and make their drives seem larger than they actually are. Combine this deception with the lost space upon formatting, and you get proportionally less total space than the manufacturer advertises.

*On top of this, operating systems take up some space for their system files, leaving the user with even less.*

#### ;-)

Comment: If you start parted as `sudo parted` then in the `parted window` you can enter `print` to see the partitions, and `print "GiB"` to see the same partitions in GiB

Comment: Yeah, now it looks almost fine.. Thanks! Got it.

Comment: @CharlesGreen whoa, I just looked up the different between GiB and GB. Didn't know that...

Comment: @Zacharee1 Personally I feel a bit cheated - I *do* understand the difference between powers of 2 and powers of 10, but [converting 1000 GiB](http://wintelguy.com/gb2gib.html) to GB indicates a 7% shortage!